# Smallest remainder using linear combination of two numbers $a$ and $b$.

Tags: linear-programming, gcd-and-lcm, tiling

Given two numbers $a$ and $b$. We need to  find all the linear combinations i.e
$$ax+by \le N$$ **such that** $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$. ****Please notice the non-negative constraint.****

What is the smallest possible remainder left when tiling $N$ using the numbers $a$ and $b$. This is also equivalent to finding the largest possible number less than or equal to $N$ expressible as the linear combination of $a$ and $b$ as this will minimize the left over / remainder in $N$. We can only use the numbers $a$ and $b$ **positive or zero number of times** **(no negatives allowed, zero is okay)**. This is just like knapsack but using two weights.

Please help me find a super optimized strategy to solve this interesting problem.

Some fact I found is that linear combination is a multiple of gcd of the two numbers, i.e $$ax + by = k\cdot gcd(a,b)$$

The generic solution is easily found out using **Bezouts identity**
and its counterpart Extended euclidean algorithm. But the problem here is the coefficients cannot be negative.

Lets hope to find some interesting solutions.

Comment: This is the Frobineus coin problem.

Comment: The largest possible $k$ so that $ax + by = k \gcd(a,b)$ is impossible to do is $k=\frac {ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2} - \frac {a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem for the case where $n=2$ (i.e. there are two variables $a$ and $b$).  This is the solution for when $\gcd(a,b)=1$ but if we divide each variable by $\gcd(a,b)$ the result follows.

Answer (score -1):

$ax + by = N$ always has integer solutions in $x, y$ iff $\gcd(a,b)|N$. If $\gcd(a,b)\not|N$ then there are no solutions. The smallest positive $k$ such that $\gcd(a,b)|N-k$  will give you the smallest possible remainder after tiling $N$ with a linear combination of integers $a,b$.

**Example 1:**

$$2x + 3y \le 10$$

If we solve for $2x + 3y = 10$ we get $(x_0, y_0) = (5,0)$ and the general solution is $x = 5 - 3 n, y = 2 n$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If we add the condition $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$, we get $5-3n \ge 0, 2n \ge 0$.

**Example 2:**

$$2x + 2y \le 11$$

In this case, $\gcd(2,2) = 2 \not|11$.

So, we check $2x + 2y = 10 \implies x + y = 5$ which has $0 \le x \le 5$ and $y = 5-x$ as solutions. Therefore, the smallest remainder is $k = 11 - 10 = 1$.

Comment: The condition that $a,b \ge 0$ disallows $ax+by= \gcd(a,b)$ and many other smaller values of $N$.

Comment: The Extended Euclidean algorithm gives you initial solution $x_0, y_0$ for a given $a,b$ and both are positive minimal solutions. We can of course rule out $a|N$ or $b|N$ as they are trivial cases that leave remainder 0 as $N$ may be tiled entirely with $a$ or $b$ since the OP mentions 0 is ok for $x,y$. The other case where $N \lt min(a,b)$ has no solutions.